# Python text to sentences when uppercase word appears

Tags: python, split

I am using Google Speech-to-Text API and after I transcribe an audio file, I end up with a text which is a conversation between two people and it doesn't contain punctuation (Google's automatic punctuation or speaker diarization features are not supported for this non-English language). For example:

```
Hi you are speaking with customer support how can i help you Hi my name is whatever and this is my problem Can you give me your address please Yes of course
```

It appears as one big sentence, but I want to split the different sentences whenever an uppercase word appears, and thus have:

```
Hi you are speaking with customer support how can i help you

Hi my name is whatever and this is my problem

Can you give me your address please

Yes of course
```

I am using Python and I don't want to use regex, instead I want to use a simpler method. What should I add to this code in order to split each result into multiple sentences as soon as I see an uppercase letter?

```
# Each result is for a consecutive portion of the audio. Iterate through
# them to get the transcripts for the entire audio file.
for i, result in enumerate(response.results):
    transcribed_text = []
    # The first alternative is the most likely one for this portion.
    alternative = result.alternatives[0]
    print("-" * 20)
    print("First alternative of result {}".format(i))
    print("Transcript: {}".format(alternative.transcript))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution would be a regex split:

```py
inp = "Hi you are speaking with customer support how can i help you Hi my name is whatever and this is my problem Can you give me your address please Yes of course"
sentences = re.split(r'\s+(?=[A-Z])', inp)
print(sentences)
```

This prints:

```
['Hi you are speaking with customer support how can i help you',
 'Hi my name is whatever and this is my problem',
 'Can you give me your address please',
 'Yes of course']
```

Note that this simple approach can easily fail should there be things like proper names in the middle of sentences, or maybe acronyms, both of which also have uppercase letters but are not markers for the actual end of the sentence.  A better long term approach would be to use a library like `nltk`, which has the ability to find sentences with much higher accuracy.